# C++ methods which take templated classes as argument

Tags: c++

I have a templated class

```
Vector<class T, int N>
```

Where T is the type of the components (double for example) and n the number of components (so N=3 for a 3D vector)

Now I want to write a method like

```
double findStepsize(Vector<double,2> v)
{..}
```

I want to do this also for three and higher dimensional vectors. Of course I could just introduce further methods for higher dimensions, but the methods would have a lot of redundant code, so I want a more generic solution. Is there a way to create a method which takes a templated class without further specializing it (in this case without specifying T or N)? Like

```
double findStepsize(Vector<T,N> v)
```

?

Comment: Surely N should be a `size_t` or `unsigned` at least. Negative components shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Thx for the hint, what's size_t?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is

```
template<typename T, int N>
double findStepsize(Vector<T,N> v)
{..}
```

If you call it with a specific `Vector<T, N>`, the compiler will *deduce* `T` and `N` to the appropriate values.

```
Vector<int, 2> v;
// ... fill ...
findStepsize(v); /* works */
```

The above value-parameter matches your example, but it's better to pass user defined classes that need to do work in their copy constructors by const reference (`Vector<T, N> const&` instead). So you avoid copies, but still can't change the caller's argument.

Answer (score 1):

Implement it this way:

```
template <typename A, int B>
class Vector {

};

template <typename T, int N>
void foo(Vector<T, N>& v) {

}

template <>
void foo(Vector<int, 3>& v) {
   // your specialization
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T find_step_size( const Vector<T,N>& v )
{
    return T(); // or something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second question answer:

You can't have a templated pointer to function, that makes no sense.
But what you can do is

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void foo(const std::vector<T>& v) {
   // do something
}

void (*ptr_foo)(const std::vector<int>&) = &foo<int>;
```

*(here the function pointers a templated function, which template argument is explicitly set to `int`)*